# Extjs with Radiogroup

Tags: extjs, store, radio-group

can we bind static json store with radiogroup in ext?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than that. What do you mean by 'bind'? They aren't normally directly related. You want to have extra radio buttons show up for each item in a store? Or..?

Comment: Yes, based on static json store (name value pair) it should display group of radio button

Answer (score 8):

Radiogroups and Stores are not directly related in ExtJS. It's easy to populate form values from a store, but using a store to actually create the fields requires a slight work around. Specifically, you would have to do something like this (assuming Ext 3.3.1), and that your JsonStore is already set up...

```
var store = <your predefined store, with records>;
var itemsInGroup = [];

store.each( function(record) {
  itemsInGroup.push( {
      boxLabel: record.someLabel, 
      name: record.someName, 
      inputValue: record.someValue
    });  
});

var myGroup = { 
  xtype: 'radiogroup', 
  fieldLabel: 'My Dynamic Radiogroup', 
  items: itemsInGroup 
};
```

Comment: But what if I just reload the store values and I want those values to be populated in checkbox group? I tried this way and it doesn't work... is there another way to dynamically change the checkbox group items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataView for this operation. Depending on store value you can  add radio buttons.
Suppose your store has 5 items than 5 radio buttons will be displayed.

```
    var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=".">', '<div class="thumb-wrap" style="width:210px; float: left;">', '<label >', '<tpl>', '<input type=radioField value={fieldId} >', '</tpl>', '{dataViewFieldName}', '</label>', '</div>', '</tpl>', {            
    });
    var me = this;

this.items = new Ext.DataView({
        store: this.store,
        tpl: tpl,            
        overClass: 'x-view-over',
        itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',           
        autoScroll: true            
    });
    this.callParent();
},
```